# Listen to modal click

Tags: angularjs

This is angularjs.
For some reason, I need to create the popup inside the controller.
So I have something like this:

```
var popupTemplate =
            '<div class="modal fade">' +
            '  <div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '    <div class="modal-content">' +
            '      <div class="modal-header">' +
            '        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
            '      </div>' +
            '      <div class="modal-body">' +
            '      <div>You sure?</div>' +
            '      </div>' +
            '      <div class="modal-footer">' +
            '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>' +
            '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>' +
            '      </div>' +
            '    </div>' +
            '  </div>' +
            '</div>';
```

To open the modal I run this:

```
var themodal = $(popupTemplate).modal();
```

I need to know if the user clicked on the OK-button.
Unfortunately adding an "ng-click" causes problems.
Nothing is executed.
I have read a little about compiling and/or using data-ng-click. But none of those worked.

So I was thinking about listening to the promise.
But having:

```
themodal.then(function(){
            console.log("test");
        })
```

Results in the error "themodal.then is not a function".

I then tried running this instead:

```
var dialog = $modal.open(popupTemplate);
dialog.result.then(function(){
    //Do stuff with respect to closure
});
```

But I then get a "$modal-open is not a fucntion".

Even though I included '$modal' in my app.

Which of them should I use and how can I make one of these approaches work?

Comment: Ditch the jQuery modal and use the uib-modal from [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970825/resolving-sync-between-mddialog-and-api-response-in-angularjs) i believe it will help you with this and give you another perspective of modal use.